# Undefined variable in JSF Expression Language

Tags: jsf, el, jsf-2.2

Is there a way to put the EL engine in to a "strict" mode?
I would like to get an error message when I reference something in EL that does not exist.

For example, I would like this to produce an error:

```
... value="#{cc.attr.attrname}" ...
```

It's misspelled. It should have been:

```
... value="#{cc.attrs.attrname}" ...
```

The default behavior appears to be:
*ignore the fact that `cc` does not have an `attr` member, and assign an empty string to `value`.*

If it matters, I'm using Mojarra 2.2.9 under Glass Fish 3.1.2.2 with

```
<class-loader delegate="false" />
<property name="useBundledJsf" value="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

EL is evaluated at runtime, so there is no way for compiler / IDE to know what some EL expression will resolve to. Your question does make sense in the context of custom components, but there is nothing stopping you from putting something like `<c:set var="cc" value="some string"/>` in the code, which would confuse the compiler / IDE.

Comment: I understand not being able to catch it at compile time. But I'd like an error at runtime, when it's evaluating the expression. If I reference a `#{someBean.nonExistantProperty}` I get  a `FacesException: The class 'SomeBean' does not have the property 'nonExistantProperty'`. However if I reference `#{nonExistantBean.nonExistantProperty}` I don't get any indication that it could not resolve `nonExistantBean`.

Comment: I didn't look at the code, but when you use `#{nonExistantBean.nonExistantProperty}`, key `nonExistingBean` is searched for in the context map. Probably there is a null check there so in case of `null` the rest of the expression is ignored. On the other hand, with `#{someBean.nonExistantProperty}`, `someBean` is already resolved to existing object, and the rest is applied to it using reflection. If an exception occurs, it is propagated further up the call stack.